# Alexa skill relative path to JSON file

Tags: c#, alexa-skills-kit

I have a little problem with my Alexa skill. I want to include display components in it, and I want to send an appropriate directive. For most of my code, I use custom classes from API, e.g.

```
Resources colorsDark = new Resources();

        colorsDark.description = "Color for dark theme";
        colorsDark.when = "${viewport.theme == 'dark'}";
```

However, for one part of my skill, I use only previously-created values, so there is no need to create new objects and assign values to them. Instead, I've created a .json file that includes all the necessary information.

I'd like to point my code to this file, but here I encountered an issue.

I'd like to make it look like this:

```
doc.Styles = [JSON_FILE]
```

However, when the function is executed, it can't find this file.

I'm using JObject from Newtonsoft.Json.

I tried to use only the relative path:

```
JObject jObject =  JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(".\\AlexaPresentationLanguage\\Styles\\ListStyle.json"));
```

as well as some other solutions like

```
Path.GetCurrentDirectory
```

and

```
Path.Combine
```

From System.IO

So far nothing worked. Do you have any ideas what can I do?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the error I get from Alexa is `error : Could not find a part of the path '/var/task/AlexaPresentationLanguage/Styles/ListStyle.json'.`

Comment: You can't do that. When need to keep your file in a S3 bucket, and get it every  tim you need to use it.